# Having trouble with a for loop in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please enter your name here $RESPONSE!"
read RESPONSE
echo "Hello $RESPONSE, I will now create a new ${RESPONSE}_file for you"
touch ${RESPONSE}_file
echo "Would you like to remove this file. If yes, please enter in all lower 
case"
read RESPONSE
if ["$RESPONSE" == "yes"];
then
rm ${RESPONSE}_file
fi
```

Hello,

I think I'm a little misguided in accomplishing my goal here. Each time I run this script I get an error message that states the "yes: command not found" error. I understand the shell is not reading this as a string. Should I create another variable that stores the result? I really have no idea at the moment how to make this work. Your input is much appreciated.

Comment: There's no `for` loop in your code. What does the title have to do with the text?

Comment: btw, `==` isn't guaranteed to work as an argument to `test` (the command also known as `[`) with `/bin/sh`. Use `=` instead -- and see the relevant specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Change `if [ "$RESPONSE" == "yes" ];` Note the space

Comment: @FredrikPihl, that's still wrong; `==` isn't robust (doesn't work with dash or ash).

Comment: True, `=` is they way to go. On mobile, was a bit to fast

Comment: @JustinHenderson, ...btw, consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: It's saying `[yes` is not found, not that `yes` is not found. That's a critical difference.

Comment: @JustinHenderson Did you get an answer?

Comment: My title was misleading, I apologize @CharlesDuffy. I did run it the code through shell check prior but I still did not achieve the desired result.